# How to create/add files or folders in firebase and access them via url like in google drive

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am able to add files to Firebase storage using reference and access them too,  but I am not sure how can I link them to a **URL** so that when a url is typed the user is navigated to that folder, like in google drive in the url there is unique id for each folder by which we can access any folder eg: "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/2/folders/1quKubZK6tPtBcik30pitM3AkXuWdjBnf", how can i link this id to the folder or file

If i have a directory like home/images/img1.png
then i want different urls to ho to /home or /home/images or /home/images/img1.png
I initially thought of using firestore database to keep a url:path mapping is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: What's wrong with storing paths in Firestore?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Storage is NOT a "directory system".  Storage ***only stores Objects*** (files).  There are no "directories" in Storage, though the Firebase Console's UI uses "magic" to make it appear as though directories exist.

Notice there are not APIs for creating a directory/folder.

Each Object in Storage has its `path`, which appears to be a directory path: `images/2023/foo.jpg`.  But `images` and `images/2023` do not actually exist.  Only the Object (`images/2023/foo.jpg`) exists.

BTW: this is the same thing with Firestore -- collections do not exist!  See my article [Firestore only has Documents](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/gregfenton/firestore-documents).